# Obtener clave del objeto json principal

Tags: firebase, vue.js, axios

Estoy consultando con axios el API REST de mi BD en Firebase y al consultar una coleccion de Cupones por ejemplo obtengo este resultado:

```
{"-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O":{"code_cr":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","coupon_id":"-Lf6LcbEF6dEkgwW0MSm","id":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","redeem_date":"2019-08-10 15:30","user_id":"-LnNxAURsniPfQE54UM0"}}
```

Estoy usando Vue JS entonces en una variable del data del componente almaceno los datos que traigo con axios, entonces en mi tabla puedo recorrer el listado de cupones asi, donde couponsRedeem es la variable del data.

```
<tr v-for="(cp,index) in couponsRedeem" v-bind:key="index">
            <td>{{cp.user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{cp.coupon_id}}</td>
            <td>{{cp.redeem_date}}</td>
             <td>{{cp.id}}</td>

             <td> <b-btn  variant="primary" size="sm" :to="{name: 'detail- 
             coupon', params:{}}">SEE MORE</b-btn></td>

        </tr>
```

Ahora lo que quiero saber es como acceder a la clave del objeto principal o sea el ID del documento?
Quiero accededer a la clave: "-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O" para mostrarla en la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias intentarlo asi:

```js
let objeto = {"-LnNzx0gvEFP71efPg2O":{"code_cr":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","coupon_id":"-Lf6LcbEF6dEkgwW0MSm","id":"-LnNw4VEKcWBxlGFZYAH","redeem_date":"2019-08-10 15:30","user_id":"-LnNxAURsniPfQE54UM0"}}; 

let couponsRedeem = [];

for (let key in objeto) {
    const item = objeto[key];
    objeto.id = key;
    couponsRedeem.push(item);
}

console.log(couponsRedeem);
console.log(couponsRedeem[0].id);
```